# How to replace particular value in all columns of csv?

Tags: linux, awk

I have this data:

```
111,24,1,\N,\N,[],aa
222,25,2,\N,\N,[],bb
333,26,3,\N,\N,[],\N
```

I want to replace all `\N` values **in the 4th and 5th columns** using `awk`.

I wrote this, but not sure that I am on the right way:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4/ "," $5/ "," $6 "," $7}'
```

This solution is not flexible. What if I have 100 columns?

**UPDATE**

Expected output:

```
111,24,1,4.3,2.1,[],aa
222,25,2,4.3,2.1,[],bb
333,26,3,4.3,2.1,[],\N
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands/ - this shows how to replace text via a command. The accepted answer uses `sed`, but there is an answer for `awk` as well.

Comment: Um, what about the third line? Does the replacement value have some formula, or will it always be: "4.3" for column 4, "2.1" for column 5, etc

Comment: @glennjackman: I want to replace all \N values in the 4th and 5th columns

Comment: @17slim: Do you mean this?: `awk '{gsub("/N","41.8297",$4);}' test` Should I use `"` or not?

Comment: Use a backslash (like in the file). You may have to escape \ (as in \\\). Where is your expected outcome coming from (what exactly are you trying to replace it *with*)? **edit:** actually I think you should drop the quotes on \N, yes (I think you still need to escape the slash)

Comment: This worked for me: `awk -F "," '{gsub(/\\N/,"41.8297",$4)}1' test > out.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    $4 == "\\N" {$4 = 4.3}
    $5 == "\\N" {$5 = 2.1}
    {print}
' file
```

or, if your real case is more complicated, something like

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        repl[4] = 4.3
        repl[5] = 2.1
        repl[7] = "hello"
    }
    {for (i in repl) if ($i == "\\N") $i = repl[i]}
    {print}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{$4=4.3;$5=2.1}1' OFS=, file

111,24,1,4.3,2.1,[],aa
222,25,2,4.3,2.1,[],bb
333,26,3,4.3,2.1,[],\N
```

Replaces values in column $4 and $5.